# Get page's content type via the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a way to get the current page's content/mime type from the DOM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox (or any other Gecko based web browser) has the [`document.contentType` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.contentType).

To do it in a standards-based way you'd have to check the headers and see if there is a meta tag with attribute `http-equiv="content-type"` and interpret its content.  Otherwise you're out of luck.

Comment: *Non-standard, only supported by Gecko. To be used in chrome code (i.e. Extensions and XUL applications).*

Comment: What if I have an 'applicaction/json' content, for example?

Comment: @guillegr123: if you've got JSON content then there is no DOM, so this question does not apply to your situation.

Answer (score 3):

If the `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="...">` tag is set, you can get its value with this Javascript:

```
var cucc=document.querySelector('meta[http-equiv="content-type"]');
alert(cucc.getAttribute('content'));
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/bvH9t/)

Should work in any modern browser and in IE8 (standards mode) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox supports document.contentType which is non-standard but reads the content-type from the HTTP headers. (**Firefox and Gecko only.** See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.contentType)) IE will need some hacking I think.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, `document` has the property `contentType`, but as far as I'm aware it's not supported in any other browser.