# Javascript get MIME type support

Tags: javascript, mime-types, mime

I found how to get mimetypes from navigator.mimeTypes:

```
function GetMimeTypes() {
    var message = "";
    var mimes = navigator.mimeTypes;
    for (var i = 0; i < mimes.length; i++) {
        message += "<b>" + mimes[i].type + "</b> : " + mimes[i].description + "/" + mimes[i].suffixes + "<br />";
    }

    var info = document.getElementById("mime");
    info.innerHTML = message;
}​
```

but it doesn't return types like
 text/html, text/css or text/javascript. I found: Naturally,several MIME types are handled by the browser itself, such as text/javascript(JavaScript files), text/css (CSS style sheets), image/gif (GIF-encoded images), image/jpegimages),text/xml (XML files), and text/html(HTML files). Many others, however, are handled by plugins and checker navigator.mimeTypes[“text/html”] != null, how can i get list of these?

Comment: it's latest mozzila firefox release

Comment: I get results like this in message: <b>application/googletalk</b> : Google voice and video chat/googletalk<br /><b>application/vnd.gtpo3d.auto</b> : /<br /><b>applicatiotn/x-vend.aol.dnupd.1</b> : ocp/ocp<br /><b>applicatiotn/x-vend.aol.dnupdater2.1</b> : ocp/ocp<br />.  Are you sure (1) that the #mime DOM element exists (2) that GetMimeTypes() is called at the right time, say on a $(document).ready()?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6309481/1370576.  This question did not have any very satisfactory answers, however.

Comment: No it's not duplicate i don't want it for one document i want browser support

Comment: because of many errors in previous text and many edits I am sending it here, I found: Naturally,several MIME types are handled by the browser itself, such as text/javascript(JavaScript files), text/css (CSS style sheets), image/gif (GIF-encoded images), image/jpegimages),text/xml (XML files), and text/html(HTML files). Many others, however, are handled by plugins and checker navigator.mimeTypes[“text/html”] != null how can i get list of these

Answer (score 0):

Using your code in Google Chrome/Firefox I get:

```
application/vnd.chromium.remoting-viewer : /
pepper-application/x-chromoting : /
application/x-nacl : Native Client Executable/nexe
application/pdf : Portable Document Format/pdf
application/x-google-chrome-print-preview-pdf : Portable Document Format/pdf
application/x-shockwave-flash : Adobe Flash movie/swf
...
etc.
```

If you're using Internet Explorer, then navigator.mimeTypes is not supported unfortunately.

See the link below for confirmation that you **cannot** get a list of mimetypes from IE:
http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/wrongWithIE/?chapter=navigator.plugins

Answer (score -2):

[Filetypes.js](https://github.com/stretchr/filetypes.js) is a project that addresses this issue by making a cross-browser API for getting mime types, descriptions and file extensions.

Comment: This library is basically just a lookup table for extensions/content-types.